# Create Azure Storage Account using C# Throw exception "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Tags: c#, ssl, azure-storage

I have a method in my asp.net mvc 5 application that uses Microsoft Azure client classes (CloudContext.Clients) to create StorageManagementClient. Needs certificate to authenticate, so I created a selfsigned certificate.

On development machine everything works ok.

On azure virtual machine(windows server 2008 r2) I have imported the certificate which is found by the code as expected, but when code that creates StorageManagementClient executes an exception is thrown

> Inner Exception Type: System.Net.WebException
>   Inner Exception: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   Inner Source: System
>   Inner Stack Trace: 
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>   Exception Type: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
>   Exception: An error occurred while sending the request.
>   Source: test
>   Stack Trace: 
>      at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageAccountOperationsExtensions.Create(IStorageAccountOperations operations, StorageAccountCreateParameters parameters)
>      at ApplicationPortal.Code.DeployAzureResources.CreateStorageAccount(SubscriptionCloudCredentials credentials, String storageName) in C:\Users\DEVSYS1\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PaSeaPortal\ApplicationPortal\Code\DeployAzureResources.cs:line 106
>      at ApplicationPortal.Controllers.AccountController.d__21.MoveNext() in C:\Users\DEVSYS1\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PaSeaPortal\ApplicationPortal\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 355

And on Event Viewer I am seeing this Error "The following fatal alert was generated: 80. The internal error state is 301."

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

> I have imported the certificate which is found by the code as expected

Do you mean that you have **installed** the selfsigned  .cer certification on the Azure virtual machine?
If it is not that case, please have a try to export the cert from your develop machine and install it on the azure virtual  machine. And try to use following code test it again.

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetCert(string thumbprint)
        {

            X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
            if (certCollection.Count <= 0) return null;
            X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
            return cert;
        }


 var thumbprint= "cert thumbprint";
 SubscriptionCloudCredentials credentials = new CertificateCloudCredentials("subscription Id", cert);
 StorageManagementClient storageManagementClient = new StorageManagementClient(credentials);
 storageManagementClient.StorageAccounts.Get("storage name"); //only classical storage can be got.
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.0.4" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net462" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Storage" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

If you try to creat **Resource management** storage account, please have try use  [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/1.0.0). We also could get more demo code from [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-resource-provider-getting-started)

Comment: I found the problem, was with privileges regarding the certificate